No Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 24.10 and Can’t Boot Back to Windows 10
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.10 on my Dell desktop PC using a USB flash drive and Balena Etcher. The installation process went smoothly, but once I logged into Ubuntu, I noticed that there’s no way for me to connect to Wi-Fi. There’s no Wi-Fi symbol in the top menu bar, and when I checked the network settings, the only available profile was for a wired connection—which was blank.
I’m new to Ubuntu, so I’m sure I must be missing something. Any guidance on how to get Wi-Fi working would be greatly appreciated!
To make things more challenging, I tried switching back to Windows 10 during boot by pressing F12, but there was no option to boot into Windows—only Ubuntu is listed. I’m now stuck with no internet access on Ubuntu and no way to switch back to Windows.

Please attach output of this terminal command: lspci -nnk -d ::0280

I don't get any output from the lspci -nnk -d ::0280 command.

I’ve managed to get internet access through a wired connection, but I’m still having issues with Wi-Fi. I’ve been troubleshooting with some help from ChatGPT, and I’ve gathered the following information, but I’m not sure if it’s enough to resolve the issue.
Here’s the situation:
USB Wi-Fi device: 0bda:c832 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ax WLAN Adapter
Error with driver: When I tried to load the r8188eu driver using the command modprobe r8188eu, the system reported that the driver was not found in the directory /lib/modules/6.11.0-8-generic.


You can try https://github.com/morrownr/rtl8852bu/tree/1.19.3
